# How to send Email from any Email address?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to send email from any email address to specific email in Asp.net C#.
ForExample: mail@example.com is the recipient name and user want to send email from yahoo or gmail or hotmail. help will be really appreciated.

```
   public bool SendMail(string message, string usermail, string userpassword)
{

    string[] emailadd = usermail.Split('@');

    string username = emailadd[0];
    string sufix = emailadd[1];
    var emailClient = new SmtpClient();
    var smtpUserInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
    //For Gmail Email
    if (sufix == "gmail.com")
        emailClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

    // For yahoo Email
    if (sufix == "yahoo.com")
        emailClient.Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";

    //For Hotmail Email
    if (sufix == "hotmail.com")
        emailClient.Host = "smtp.live.com";

    emailClient.Port = 587;
    emailClient.EnableSsl = true;
    smtpUserInfo.UserName = usermail;
    smtpUserInfo.Password = userpassword;
    emailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    emailClient.Credentials = smtpUserInfo;
    const string subject = "Subect Here";

    var msg = new MailMessage(usermail, "info@abc.net", subject, message) { IsBodyHtml = true };
    emailClient.Send(msg);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Good luck, let us know how you get on

Comment: This is something for a search engine, not this site.

Comment: Welcome to [stackoverflow] (http://stackoverflow.com/tour) please share what you have tried. then if you got stucked with some exact issue, we will help you. Refer these links for asking proper questions (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , (http://stackoverflow.com//help/mcve) and (http://sscce.org)

Comment: Tell me your problem.... What was the error?

Comment: Actually i just want to know that it is necessary to login for a user to send an email and gives his or her password ?

Comment: It works for me like a charm i just posted it to get improve and some useful suggestions to improve my skills

Answer (score 3):

[image]

### Sample Code

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

string smtpAddress = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
int portNumber = 587;
bool enableSSL = true;

string emailFrom = "email@yahoo.com";
string password = "abcdefg";
string emailTo = "someone@domain.com";
string subject = "Hello";
string body = "Hello, I'm just writing this to say Hi!";

using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
{
    mail.From = new MailAddress(emailFrom);
    mail.To.Add(emailTo);
    mail.Subject = subject;
    mail.Body = body;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    // Can set to false, if you are sending pure text.

    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("C:\\SomeFile.txt"));
    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("C:\\SomeZip.zip"));

    using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, portNumber))
    {
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(emailFrom, password);
        smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
        smtp.Send(mail);
    }
}
```

Referred [From](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/520998/Send-Email-from-Yahoo-GMail-Hotmail-Csharp)

---

### Edit

- Your codes looks good, but only problem is your receive address*(info@abc.com)* .

> Please put correct email address on receive address instead of `info@abc.com`. also please take some idea from the above sample codes.

Answer (score 1):

Yse your Google email id to send mails through your #. Usually most of us who don't have their mailing hosts with them can use this simple code to make a program that could send mails to any SMTP Web hosts. I have made one and I want to share it with all of you. Please comment on how this could be made more attractive.

```
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xyz@gmail.com", "password");
SmtpServer.Port = 587;
SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
mail = new MailMessage();
String[] addr = TextBox1.Text.Split(',');
try
{
   mail.From = new MailAddress("youremail@gmail.com","Your Name", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
   Byte i;
   for( i = 0;i< addr.Length; i++)
     mail.To.Add(addr[i]);

   mail.Subject = TextBox3.Text;
   mail.Body = TextBox4.Text;
   if(ListBox1.Items.Count != 0)
   {
      for(i = 0;i<ListBox1.Items.Count;i++)
        mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ListBox1.Items[i].ToString()));
   }
   SmtpServer.Send(mail);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Error" +ex.ToString());
}
```